# Ubuntu 15.10 account-plugin-twitter not showing in Online Accounts when adding

Tags: gnome

As the subject says I don't have the option to add a twitter account. It's a fresh install with all updates and I've manually forced re-installation of the twitter account plugin with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install account-plugin-twitter -y
```

Am hoping someone else has come across this or has an idea what to try next.

Comment: Does anyone have it working?